# Call method of a runnable instance outside the runnable that is executed by the runnable's thread

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

The question is confusing, but thats what i want to do:

```
public class Main
{
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    Thread secondThread = new Thread(instance);

    public static void main()
    {
         secondThread.start();
         //here i want to call foo(), but be processed by secondThread thread(not the Main thread)
    }
}


public class MyClass implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {

    }

    public void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

If i use "instance.foo();" it will be processed by the Main thread.

Comment: Yes, I'm already running from it..

Answer (score 5):

The idea of a `Runnable` is that it's a consolidated piece of code that can be executed by something else inside of whatever context it chooses (in this case, a thread). The second thread will call the `run()` method when it starts, so you may want to have a call to `foo()` within your `MyClass.run()` method. You cannot arbitrarily decide, from the main thread, that the second thread is now going to abandon whatever it was doing in the `run()` method and start working on `foo()`.

Comment: "You cannot arbitrarily decide, from the main thread, that the second thread is now going to abandon whatever it was doing in the run() method and start working on foo()."

I don't know what you mean when you say, "you cannot arbitrarily decide", but it is possible to run foo from the main method while some runnable object infinite loops in its `run()` method. So, what's happening when the main method calls 'run()'? Is it simply run from the main process's thread?

Comment: @DaleMarkowitz If the `main` method directly invokes `run` then `run` will be executed in whatever thread that `main` happens to be executing in. The OP was wanting to take control of a different thread and divert its execution to a different function (i.e. arbitrarily decide) which is not directly possible.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call a thread, you can only signal it.  If you want foo() to be executed, you have to signal run() to ask it to execute foo().

Comment: In case foo() returns, for example, a reference to another object, and I call it the way it's done in the example, what would be the value returned by foo()?

Answer (score 1):

change your code as below:

```
public class Main
{
    Object signal = new Object();
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    Thread secondThread = new Thread(instance);

    public static void main()
    {
         instance.setSignal(signal);
         secondThread.start();
          synchronize(signal)
          { 
         try{
          signal.notify();**//here will notify the secondThread to invoke the foo()**
         }
         catch(InterrupedException e)
         {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}


public class MyClass implements Runnable
{
    Object signal;
    public setSignal(Object sig)
    {
        signal = sig;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       synchronize(signal)
       { 
         try{
          signal.wait();
         }
         catch(InterrupedException e)
         {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
        this.foo();

    }

    public void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd modify your class to contain an Executor, and then have it's methods ask the executor to run the task.  By passing the executor into MyClass's constructor, main controls how the tasks get executed.

```
public class Main
{
   Executor runner = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
   MyClass instance = new MyClass(runner);

   public static void main()
   {
        instance.foo();
        // cleanup executor
   }
}


public class MyClass
{
   private final Executor runner;

   public MyClass(Executor runner)
   {
      this.runner = runner;
   }

   public void foo()
   {
       runner.execute(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
             System.out.println("foo");
          }
       });
   }
}
```